# How to check for a column in DB and create record while using relationship

Tags: laravel

I want that whenever ModelMeta is created it should check that modelable_id is unique.Means modelable_id should be not repeated in the ModelMetas table.
Thank you.
This is the Relation on News Model

```
public function validatedOn(){
        return $this->morphMany(ModelMeta::class,'modelable');
    }
```

This is the Relation on ModelMeta

```
public function modelable(){

        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

This is the method being used

```
public function addValidationDateToMeta($newsId,$transitionName){
            $news = News::findOrFail($newsId);
            $workflow = Workflow::get($news,'news_status');
            $workflow->apply($news, $transitionName); // applying transition
            $news->save();
            $param = [
                'modelable_id' => $newsId,
                'modelable_type' => News::class,
                'fields'    =>json_encode(['validated_on' =>Carbon::now()]),
            ];
            ModelMeta::create($param);
            return $news;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for `ModelMeta` record with `$newsId` before you create a new one, like this:

```
$alreadyExists = ModelMeta::where('modelable_id', $newsId)->first();
if($alreadyExists){
   //value already exists, return different response or something else
}else{
   //It doens't exist, create it
   ModelMeta::create($param);
}
```

Also, If you didn't do it already, I would suggest you to make your `modelable_id` field [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-indexes)  in your migration:

```
$table->integer('modelable_id')->unique();
```

This will also prevent any duplicate data being entered in your table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to do this using validatedOn method because further I have to use this in resource.